# Wiring a ceiling fan to the house wiring

Tags: wiring

My ceiling fan came with black (motor), red(light), white (neutral) and green (ground), but at my home I have: three white together, three black together, one blue and two red together. 
What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have separate light and fan switches on the wall. Just substitute the red wire from your new unit to the connections the blue wire used to go to. Do everything else exactly as it was.  The blue is light on your old unit, so same function as red on your new one.